# I need help formatting an xml file and are being asked to create a xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need help formatting an XML file and are being asked to create an XSLT file to be seen in a browser and it doesn't have to be super fancy.  I have created the XML code and I have an example XSLT file and thought I could swap out the values for my assignment but can't get anything to show up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my XSLT file for my assignment.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
    <xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/PLAYER">
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:6px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="LEAGUE_NAME"/> League- </span>
      </div>
      <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="DIVISION_NAME"/> Division- </span>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:22px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:12pt">
        <p>
          <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
            <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="Team_NAME"/> Team- </span>
          </div>
          <span style="font-style:italic"> (<xsl:value-of select="GIVEN_NAME/SURNAME"/>PLayer Name)</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Here is my xml file for the assignment.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Season.xslt" ?>
  <SEASON>
    <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
    <LEAGUE>
      <LEAGUE_NAME>National</LEAGUE_NAME>
      <DIVISION>
        <DIVISION_NAME>East</DIVISION_NAME>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Florida</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Marlins</TEAM_NAME>
          <PLAYER>
            <GIVEN_NAME>Eric</GIVEN_NAME>
            <SURNAME>Ludwick</SURNAME>
            <POSITION>Starting Pitcher</POSITION>
            <GAMES>13</GAMES>
            <GAMES_STARTED>6</GAMES_STARTED>
            <WINS>1</WINS>
            <LOSSES>4</LOSSES>
            <SAVES>0</SAVES>
            <COMPLETE_GAMES>0</COMPLETE_GAMES>
            <SHUT_OUTS>0</SHUT_OUTS>
            <ERA>7.44</ERA>
            <INNINGS>32.2</INNINGS>
            <EARNED_RUNS>31</EARNED_RUNS>
            <HIT_BATTER>27</HIT_BATTER>
            <WILD_PITCHES>0</WILD_PITCHES>
            <BALK>2</BALK>
            <WALKED_BATTER>0</WALKED_BATTER>
            <STRUCK_OUT_BATTER>17</STRUCK_OUT_BATTER>
          </PLAYER>
          <PLAYER>
            <GIVEN_NAME>Brian</GIVEN_NAME>
            <SURNAME>Daubach</SURNAME>
            <POSITION>First Base</POSITION>
            <GAMES>10</GAMES>
            <GAMES_STARTED>3</GAMES_STARTED>
            <AT_BATS>15</AT_BATS>
            <RUNS>0</RUNS>
            <HITS>3</HITS>
            <DOUBLES>1</DOUBLES>
            <TRIPLES>0</TRIPLES>
            <HOME_RUNS>0</HOME_RUNS>
            <RBI>3</RBI>
            <STEALS>0</STEALS>
            <CAUGHT_STEALING>0</CAUGHT_STEALING>
            <SACRIFICE_HITS>0</SACRIFICE_HITS>
            <SACRIFICE_FLIES>0</SACRIFICE_FLIES>
            <ERRORS>0</ERRORS>
            <WALKS>1</WALKS>
            <STRUCK_OUT>5</STRUCK_OUT>
            <HIT_BY_PITCH>1</HIT_BY_PITCH>
          </PLAYER>
        </TEAM>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Montreal</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Expos</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>New York</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Mets</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Philadelphia</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Phillies</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
      </DIVISION>
      <DIVISION>
        <DIVISION_NAME>Central</DIVISION_NAME>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Chicago</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Cubs</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
      </DIVISION>
      <DIVISION>
        <DIVISION_NAME>West</DIVISION_NAME>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Arizona</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Diamondbacks</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
      </DIVISION>
    </LEAGUE>
    <LEAGUE>
      <LEAGUE_NAME>American</LEAGUE_NAME>
      <DIVISION>
        <DIVISION_NAME>East</DIVISION_NAME>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Baltimore</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Orioles</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
      </DIVISION>
      <DIVISION>
        <DIVISION_NAME>Central</DIVISION_NAME>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Chicago</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>White Sox</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
      </DIVISION>
      <DIVISION>
        <DIVISION_NAME>West</DIVISION_NAME>
        <TEAM>
          <TEAM_CITY>Anaheim</TEAM_CITY>
          <TEAM_NAME>Angels</TEAM_NAME>
        </TEAM>
      </DIVISION>
    </LEAGUE>
  </SEASON>
```

I am trying to get it to look similar to my other assignment

Here is th example XSLT file that I was using for a breakfast XML file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">
  <xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/food">
    <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
      <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
      <xsl:value-of select="price" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="description" />
        <span style="font-style:italic"> (<xsl:value-of select="calories"/> calories per serving)</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start off by doing this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/PLAYER">
```

But this will look for an element called `PLAYER` that is a direct child of `SEASON`. But `PLAYER` elements are nested away in `LEAGUE`, `DIVISION` and `TEAM` so your `xsl:for-each` should look like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER">
```

But, within this you then do this..

```
<xsl:value-of select="LEAGUE_NAME"/>
```

This is a problem are now positioned on the `PLAYER` element, and so it will look for a direct child called `LEAGUE_NAME` of which there are none. You need to navigate back up the tree to get the league name

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../../LEAGUE_NAME"/>
```

(Where `..` gets the parent node)

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER">
  <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:6px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="../../../LEAGUE_NAME"/> League- </span>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="../../DIVISION_NAME"/> Division- </span>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left:22px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:12pt">
    <p>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="../TEAM_NAME"/> Team- </span>
      </div>
      <span style="font-style:italic"> (<xsl:value-of select="concat(GIVEN_NAME, ' ', SURNAME)"/>)</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

However, perhaps you really want to avoid repeated the the league, division and team? In this case, you can nest your `xsl:for-each` statements

```
<xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/LEAGUE[.//PLAYER]">
  <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:6px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="LEAGUE_NAME"/> League- </span>
  </div>
  <xsl:for-each select="DIVISION[.//PLAYER]">
    <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
      <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="DIVISION_NAME"/> Division- </span>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left:22px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:12pt">
      <p>
        <xsl:for-each select="TEAM[PLAYER]">
          <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
            <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="TEAM_NAME"/> Team- </span>
          </div>
          <xsl:for-each select="PLAYER">
            <span style="font-style:italic"> (<xsl:value-of select="concat(GIVEN_NAME, ' ', SURNAME)"/>)</span>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </p>
    </div>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note the use of the condition `[.//PLAYER]` so that elements, such as `LEAGUE` are only output if there is at least one player as a descendant.

Comment: ok so like for each nested statement depending on which part I am doing it would look like this <xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER"> is that correct? Or do I also need to include the DIVISION_NAME or TEAM_NAME in the for-each statement?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">

<xsl:for-each select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/PLAYER">
  <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:6px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/LEAGUE_NAME"/> League- </span>
  </div>   Here is part of what I have:

Comment: <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/DIVISION_NAME"/> Division- </span>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-left:22px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:12pt">
    <p>
      <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em;font-size:10pt">
        <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="/SEASON/LEAGUE/DIVISION/TEAM/TEAM_NAME"/> Team- </span>
      </div>
      <span style="font-style:italic"> (<xsl:value-of select="concat(GIVEN_NAME, ' ', SURNAME)"/>)</span>
    </p></div>
last part.

Comment: when I view this now in a browser I get the names and all but it is showing up in a single line straight across.

Comment: Starting a Xpath expression with `/` means it will select from the top level document node. You need your statements to be relative to the current path node. So, if you have selected a LEAGUE, you just need to do `<xsl:for-each select="DIVISION" />` to get the divisions in that league.

Comment: ok and how do i get it to be going down the side of the page instead of across the top of the page?  And I want to add some color to it and style it so it looks a little bit nicer.  Thanks!

Comment: That's probably warrants a new question, as that is more about HTML and CSS than XSLT. Before writing any XSLT you should really know what you want the output to look like. So, work out what the HTML and CSS will be for your desired output, then come back to write the XSLT.